# Use config and node_modules, in my sub-projects inside of my webpack npm main project

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, npm, webpack

I have a MAIN PROJECT, with mutiple sub-projects.
I did the webpack.config.js and I install all the NPM node_modules I need (jQuery/Bootstrap/SASS/minifyiers/etc...).
And I want to use them in my sub projects, how can I do it?

This is my Project directory-tree example
* I want to use that file/folder in my sub-projects

```
MAIN PROJECT
    -assets/
    -node_modules/ *
    -index.php
    -package.json
    -webpack.config.js *

    -PROJECT.1
        -assets/
        -package.json
        -index.php
    -PROJECT.2
        -assets/
        -package.json
        -index.php
    -PROJECT.3
        -assets/
        -package.json
        -index.php
```

When I try the npm run dev in the sub-projects, NPM says to me I need the node_modules.
But I want to use the webpack configuration and the node_modules of the MAIN PROJECT

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use relative route...

For example in PROJECT.1/package.json add the following in the dependencies:

```
"package-name": "link:../node_modules/package-name",
```

Comment: but what that do ?